# Generating Instagram public Short link

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm trying to generate codes for instagram's public pictures which are outputted as such: http://instagram.com/p/oQX6_5A8B7/

Now I've got this script which outputs 100 codes but they don't seem valid and I'm not sure how to improve the generation to make them more valid:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var instaURL = 'http://instagram.com/p/o';
var randText = randomString();

function randomString() {
    var chars = "-_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 9;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomstring;
    }
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    var output = '<a href="'+instaURL+randomString()+'"/>'+instaURL+randomString()+'</a><br>';
    document.write(output);
}
</script>
```

Any thought on this?

Comment: Why are you trying to randomly download instagram files like this? Why not just grab a feed...

Comment: Well it's more to know if I can generate the same public links for my profile or not.